# pdfgrep pattern to include/exclude linebreak

Tags: regex, pdf, grep, multiline

`pdfgrep` works like `grep` except that it acts on pages instead of lines. How can I craft a regular expression with a newline character?

I want to look for `a`, followed by any number of characters *except linebreaks*, followed by `b`, but `pdfgrep 'a[^\n]*b'` doesn't work, whereas `pdfgrep 'a.*b'` returns results that span multiple lines. (I've examined the output with `xxd` to confirm that these newlines are indeed `\x0A`.)

Comment: Try `pdfgrep -P 'a.*b'`

Comment: Thanks, @WiktorStribiżew !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, `pdfgrep` uses a POSIX compliant regex flavor where `.` matches any char including line break chars.

Fortunately, [`pdfgrep` also supports](https://pdfgrep.org/doc.html) PCRE regex flavor with the help of `-P` flag. In a PCRE regex flavor, `.` matches any char but line break chars.

Thus, you can use

```
pdfgrep -P 'a.*b'
```