# How to prevent zsh from escaping backslash in arguments to command?

Tags: escaping, zsh

I type this line in *zsh* to find a backslash followed by a lowercase n: 
`pdfgrep "\\n" <some path>` 
(P.S. [pdfgrep](https://pdfgrep.org), doing grep on PDFs)

Then *zsh* will first escape double backslash into a single backslash, resulting in what *pdfgrep* see is `"\n" <some path>`, i.e. searching for a line feed (LF).

How to prevent *zsh* from first escaping backslash in arguments to command?

Comment: This may be useful: [Difference between single and double quotes in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753). Most of what's there also applies to `zsh`.

Comment: Exactly! @Gairfowl

Answer (score 0):

hello, hope you are doing well,

Thank you for your question, I didnt know pdfgrep :p

First, I downloaded a pdf (this one exactly https://www.docker.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/03/docker-cheat-sheet.pdf)

then I tried the simple:

```
❯ pdfgrep '\n' docker-cheat-sheet.pdf
```

but didnt work as you know.

Then like you, I tried this:

```
pdfgrep '\\n' docker-cheat-sheet.pdf
```

but there was no output.

I decided to try to escape the \n with an echo command to test:

as expected, this interprete the \n:

```
❯ echo -e "test\ntest"
test
test
```

then I tried this, but it didnt work also:

```
❯ echo -e "test\\ntest"
test
test
```

then I tried this, and it worked with the echo command:

```
❯ echo -e "test\\\ntest"
test\ntest
```

So i decided to try it on the pdf, but still no output:

```
❯ pdfgrep '\\\n' docker-cheat-sheet.pdf
```

then, I have found this topic: [pdfgrep pattern to include/exclude linebreak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62804727/pdfgrep-pattern-to-include-exclude-linebreak)

and tried this:

```
❯ pdfgrep -P '\n' docker-cheat-sheet.pdf
```

I think this do the job, is it what you was looking for?

bguess

Comment: No. It's not RegExp Engine's problem, so whether ```-P``` doesn't matter. Actually finding ```\\n``` is just a special example; the general problem is preventing escaping backslash, like that in ```\\d```(number otherwise), ```\\b```(word boundary otherwise), ```\\r```(carriage return otherwise).

Comment: Ok Let's just resume to better understand, when you pdfgrep a PDF with \n you want to grep New Lines or the opposite, meaning you want to grep the character "\n"?

Comment: Every word is positive, but what do you mean by "the opposite"?

Comment: meaning you want to grep exactly the pattern "\n" ? (sorry for my english)

Comment: But wait, no output to "pdfgrep '\\n' docker-cheat-sheet.pdf" or "pdfgrep '\\n' docker-cheat-sheet.pdf" means that there is no "\n" pattern in the pdf right?